# Rails console sandbox mode doesn't rollback when I exit from a project which connects to multiple DBs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sandbox, rollback

I am using Rails5 and connecting multiple DBs from one project.
(By defining new database.yml for extra DB. Just like written in https://medium.com/alturasoluciones/using-multiple-databases-on-rails-74ba29a2a840)

When I use

```
bundle exec rails c --sandobx
```

the main DB defined in `config/database.yml` rolls back but the extra db doesn't.
Do I need to add extra configurations to enable sandbox mode for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems `--sandbox` option doesn't wrap your custom db connection with transaction by default. So you have to do it by yourself.

ref: [active_record/railties/console_sandbox.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/977d77e9e250a323f64785042d9ad8412368c19a/activerecord/lib/active_record/railties/console_sandbox.rb)

You can write a custom console setting in application config file, so try something like this:

```
# config/environments/development.rb

console do |app|
  if app.sandbox?
    CacheBase.connection.begin_transaction(joinable: false)
    at_exit do
      CacheBase.connection.rollback_transaction
    end
  end
end
```

I haven't tried myself (because there's a lot to setup a second db like yours...), but I hope this helps :)